# Javascript - improving on a nested if-else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, refactoring

I have a horrible nested if. There could in the future be even more lines.

```
if (people < 10) {
    price = 500;
} else if (people >= 10 && people < 25) {
    price = 350;
} else if (people >= 25 && people < 100) {
    price = 250;
} else if (people >= 100) {
    price = 200;
}
```

The price goes down as the volume goes up. How do I refactor this to make it more maintainable/readable?

Edit: I tried a switch and it was not any better?

Comment: Yes sorry a typo. Fixed.

Comment: _I tried a switch.._ And why didn't you like it?

Comment: Passing (true) into it seemed a bit hacky, plus there was little difference to the nested if.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use an array that defines the thresholds, then `.find` the appropriate value in the array. This will be very concise, especially when there are lots of thresholds:

```js
const thresholds = [
  [100, 200], // need 100+ people for the price to be 200
  [25, 250], // else need 25+ people for the price to be 250
  [10, 350],
  [0, 500]
];
function findPrice(people) {
  return thresholds.find(([limit]) => people >= limit)[1];
}

console.log(findPrice(53)); // 53 people
console.log(findPrice(25));
console.log(findPrice(24));
```

Comment: Not at all, unless you have something like thousands of thresholds *and* are running the function hundreds of times per second, or something like that. Code readability and conciseness is more important in 99% of situations.

Comment: @AlexanderDavidson I think that the performance you loss is worth the maintainability of it. Now that you have an object iteration, you can easily add new treatment or new threshold. I would 100% always prefer object iteration to plain if/else statements

Answer (score 3):

You could take a function with early exit. The previous check is the condition for the next check or for getting the maximum result.

The advantage is to prevent chains of `else if`statements and to offer a better maintanability.

```
function getPrice(people) {
    if (people < 10) {
        return 500;
    } 
    if (people < 25) {
        return 350;
    }
    if (people < 100) {
        return 250;
    }
    return 200;
}

var price = getPrice(people);
```

More to read:

- [Should I return from a function early or use an if statement?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer? How returning in separate if block is better than else if's?

Answer (score 1):

Well you dont need the check for `>=`, when the check will stay in this form:

```
if (people < 10) {
    price = 500; 
} else if (people < 25) { 
    price = 350;
} else if (people < 100) { 
    price = 250; 
} else { 
    //people count is implicitly greater than 100
    price = 200; 
}
```

On each (next) step the people count is implicitly greater than the previous check, so eg. if `people < 10` results in `false` the value is implicitly greater than 9 or `>= 10`. For this reason the duplicate check is not needed an thus can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function applyConf(v) {
  return [{
    // false means infinite
    min: false,
    max: 9,
    value: 500,
  }, {
    min: 10,
    max: 24,
    value: 350,
  }, {
    min: 25,
    max: 99,
    value: 250,
  }, {
    min: 100,
    max: false,
    value: 200,
  }].find(({
    min,
    max,
  }) => (min === false || v >= min) && (max === false || v <= max)).value;
}

console.log(applyConf(-10));
console.log(applyConf(8));
console.log(applyConf(20));
console.log(applyConf(80));
console.log(applyConf(100));
console.log(applyConf(100000));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer instead of to many if to use switch condition as below

```
function getPrice(people)
{
    switch(true){
        case people<10: return 500;
        case people<25: return 350;
        case people<100: return 250;
        default: return 200;
    }

}
```